# How to automatically sign a message using PGP in an email?

Tags: pgp, openpgp

Is there any way to sign and send a message from email server automatically...without using any desktop client to sign the message.

For Example, A wants to send a message to B. A open its email account, composes message and click on 'send'. After pressing send button message should be automatically signed by PGP private key and deliver to B. A don't want to use desktop client to copy message, then sign and then compose and then send...manually

Comment: It is not fully clear what you are doing but the `gpg` command line tool does can be used to automatically sign messages. Sending is then another tool (and unrelated to security).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich For Example, A wants to send a message to B. A open its email account, composes message and click send. After pressing send button message should be automatically signed by PGP private key and deliver to B. A don't want to use desktop client to copy message, then sign and then compose and then send...manually

Comment: As I said, this is possible using the gpg command line tool. Of course it needs to have access to your private key in an unencrypted form or somehow has access to the password for the key. So the tools are there but how exactly combine these within your specific setup is not a security question. There are [mail gateways](https://www.google.com/search?q=mail+gateway+pgp+sign) though which offer such capabilities of transparent signing, encrypting and decrypting, although most offer this for S/MIME.

Comment: Yeah, I think you should look into S/MIME. Email clients commonly support it.